# SQL Server/Oracle table writable only by a trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, triggers, readonly

I am wondering if is there a way to make a table writable only by an specific trigger in SQL Server or Oracle DB.
Just to make an example:

---

```
Table: "Operation"
```

> **ID | Date   | Account1_ID | Account2_ID | Amount**

---

```
Table: "Transactions"
```

> **ID | Date | Account | Debt | Credit**

---

What I want to ensure is that the **Transactions** table only receive data from a trigger in the **Operation** table.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: What is the business problem that you're trying to solve?  Depending on the definition of "ensure" and "only" (are you trying to prevent a rogue DBA from writing an ad hoc `insert` statement that adds a row to this table, trying to prevent a rogue developer from maliciously adding code to a procedure that writes to this table, trying to prevent a developer from accidentally manipulating the table outside the trigger) we may be able to come up with a technical implmentation but there may be a simpler way to solve the underlying problem.

Comment: @JustinCave I want to prevent a developer from accidentally manipulating the table outside the trigger. This is not in production.

Comment: On the Oracle side, can the developers log in to the database as the user that owns the `transactions` table?

Comment: @JustinCave. This is an hypothetic case but, yes they may be able to log in as the owner of that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Execute As](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx) allows you to create a trigger that runs as a user different to the current user.
So you can create a separate user who has write access to your TRANSACTIONS table, and execute the trigger as that user.

If no other users have write access, only the trigger user can modify the data.

Of course you then need to make sure nobody can log in as that user, and that you can trust your DBA to manage the account.

Comment: If it works for you, please accept the answer so others know this is the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a solution that does something like `alter table TRANSACTIONS read only` inside of a trigger you're going to be disappointed because you can't include DDL inside of a trigger due it giving an implicit commit ([this is a very good thing](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:698152300346710865)).

I guess the real question you have to answer is what you really mean by *only receive data from a trigger in the operation table*. Are you afraid of other users inserting data directly into that table? What does your application logic do? Does it handle this?

Comment: Yes I want to ensure in the database tier that no one can insert/update/delete in this table except by inserting rows in the Operations table. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: @LeonardoM, I'm going to assume this is production data and say why does anyone have the **ability** to write into a table directly? If they do revoke that ability immediately. If you have further concerns consider moving that table into another schema and grant the application schema write privileges.