# SQL Server security - stored procedures

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to implement security on our applications (which consist mainly of websites using SQL Server stored procedures).

Microsoft seem to suggest that best practice is to wrap all data functionality in stored procedures which we have done. Our structure is something like:

- SQL Server database - `[data1]`
- SQL Server database - `[webSPs]`
- PHP / Symfony web apps

All the data resides in tables in `[data1]` and on the same server is another 'database' which just contains the stored procedures used by the web apps.

The SQL Server has a login 'webapp' which, as a user on `[webSPs]`, has permissions just to run the stored procedures in `[webSPs]`.

However, as these stored procedures read, write, append data on the `[data1]` tables, this user has to be a member of `db_datawriter` and `db_datareader` database roles in `[data1]`.

This all works fine, but it seems there is a hole in the security here, as its then possible for a user accessing `[webSPs]` to not only run the stored procedures but write to any underlying table - is it possible to give permission that say something like:

> you can read/write to tables on this database but only through SPs - not directly

From what I've read, I think it would work as I hoped if there wasn't the second database which I guess is breaking ownership chaining.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What was the motivation to put the stored procedures *in another* database? That seems to make things unnecessarily more complicated than they need to be ....

Comment: The user does not have to be a member of db_datawrite to write data from a stored procedure. If they have permission to execute the procedure they will be able to write data. So yes, to answer your question you do not allow this user to write directly to the tables but give them execute permission on the procedures.

Comment: Sean, where the tables are in a different database, if the user does not have explicit read/write data permissions, it returns an error: "SELECT permission denied on..."  I think this is because the SPs are in another database (as per Marc's comments above) Just wondering if there is a way around this as I would like to keep the separation if possible.

Comment: It is remarkable that [another, very similar, question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27228709/sql-server-oracle-table-writable-only-by-a-trigger "SQL Server/Oracle table writable only by a trigger?") was asked only about half an hour before yours. I believe the accepted answer to that question should apply to stored procedures just as well as to triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it's frankly a pain to implement. You can use module signing. Essentially, you:

1. Create a certificate in your WebSps database.
2. Backup and restore the certificate to the data1 database
3. Create a user from the certificate
4. Grant whatever read and write permissions to the certificate-based user in data1
5. Sign any stored procedure you want to use cross-database with the certificate by calling the `add signature` syntax

Keep in mind that every time that you change the procedure (either via alter or drop and create), the signature gets lost. So you'll be in a constant cycle of re-signing. You can read more about the process of module signing [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345102%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)